# Missing vim indentation files

Tags: apache, vim, indentation

I've always wondered why vim lacks some indentation files that would be handy for everyday life. Example: I sometimes have to deal with really messed up apache config files (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/*`). It's impossible to have them indented correctly by vim. With apache config files I usually try to improve indentation by typing

```
:set ft=xml
gg=G
:set ft=apache
```

I know that apache configuration files are not XML and that XML indentation doesn't work remarkably good here, but at least it's better than having every config line in the first column. There's a [vim script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1784) which seems to work correctly but I have to install it on all Linux systems. If we take this plugin as an example: It's from 2007 - why did it never make it into a vim release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maintainer of the [indent] script has to submit the file to Bram (Vim's BDFL) for inclusion (and commit to maintaining it); that's how the process works. So, if you want to have this in the runtime, please ask the maintainer, or, (as the last update of that script on vim.org is from 2007 and he may be gone), ask on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) for someone to volunteer as such.

But... you shouldn't have to rely on those files being in the official runtime. Unless you're an atypical user without *any* customization, you must already have a mechanism in place to distribute your personal `~/.vimrc` and plugins; if you put the script into `~/.vim/indent/`, you should be all set.

Comment: You're right; currently I'm able to install my vimrc from internet, but I should add other configuration files.

Comment: Many put their config into a GitHub repo and clone that. Plugins can also be added as Git submodules. Or have a look at the Vundle plugin manager, which handles most of it.